# Stored Procedure Case statement override each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the modified version of my previous post. please help me with this.
In case sub query i am getting correct result. but when i run full sp Alert case and Field case are overriding each other.

[Getting null value in status field, can anyone explain what I am going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596862/getting-null-value-in-status-field-can-anyone-explain-what-i-am-going-wrong)

```
(CASE       
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT [GunSerialNo] FROM [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] 
                WHERE aig.ModifiedOn IS NOT NULL 
                  AND aig.CreatedOn IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 'In Armory'

    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT aig.GunSerialNo 
                FROM [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] AS aig 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                            FROM 
                                (SELECT GunSerialNo, DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) AS TIME_ADDED 
                                 FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]) ag 
                            WHERE ag.TIME_ADDED<GETUTCDATE()) abd ON abd.GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
                WHERE aig.ModifiedOn IS NULL
                  AND aig.CreatedBy IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 'Alert' 

    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT aig.GunSerialNo 
                 FROM [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] AS aig 
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                             FROM 
                                 (SELECT GunSerialNo, DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) AS TIME_ADDED 
                                  FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]) ag 
                             WHERE ag.TIME_ADDED>GETUTCDATE()) abd ON abd.GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
                 WHERE aig.ModifiedOn IS NULL
                   AND aig.CreatedBy IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 'In Field'
 END) AS [Status],
FROM 
    [dbo].[CarryAndUseLicence] cl 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Branch] b ON b.[BranchId] = cl.[BranchId]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Gun] gun ON cl.[GunSerialNo] = gun.[SerialNo]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] aig ON aig.[StaffId] = cl.[StaffId]
```

Comment: Try replace all sub query with a valid result and run the procedure, check if it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the double use of the alias **aig**. The alias in the Exists-query overrides the alias from the top query.  As a result of this, the Exists-query does not include the current record but looks at the entire table.

How It works:

```
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT aig2.GunSerialNo 
            FROM [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] AS aig2 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM 
                            (SELECT GunSerialNo, DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) AS TIME_ADDED 
                             FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]) ag 
                        WHERE ag.TIME_ADDED<GETUTCDATE()) abd ON abd.GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
            WHERE aig2.ModifiedOn IS NULL
              AND aig2.CreatedBy IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 'Alert' 

WHEN EXISTS (SELECT aig2.GunSerialNo 
             FROM [dbo].[ArmouryIssueGun] AS aig2 
             INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                         FROM 
                             (SELECT GunSerialNo, DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) AS TIME_ADDED 
                              FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]) ag 
                         WHERE ag.TIME_ADDED>GETUTCDATE()) abd ON abd.GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
             WHERE aig2.ModifiedOn IS NULL
               AND aig2.CreatedBy IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 'In Field'
```

or shorter

```
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]
             WHERE GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
               AND DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) < GETUTCDATE() 
               AND ModifiedOn IS NULL
               AND CreatedBy  IS NOT NULL
              )
    THEN 'Alert' 

WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]
             WHERE GunSerialNo = aig.GunSerialNo
               AND DATEADD(HOUR, EstimatedTime, CreatedOn) > GETUTCDATE() 
               AND ModifiedOn IS NULL
               AND CreatedBy  IS NOT NULL
              )
    THEN 'In Field'
```